# Win32 Device Context without Window

Tags: c++, winapi

In my application i need to create HBITMAP objects to which I render and from where I copy the result.

I use the function "CreateDIBSection" to create these bitmaps, however this function required a DC (Device Context) as first parameter. Currently I get this by calling GetDC(hWnd) on the main windows handle (hWnd). But I would like to be able to create HBITMAPS without the requirement of having an application window, without some kind of in memory DC, Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CreateCompatibleDC(NULL)` will create you a device context that is compatible with the screen - which sounds like it would be ideal in the situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can get one with CreateDC for the display:

```
 HDC hDc = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Cleanup with DeleteDC().  It is only used to initialize the palette for bitmaps with indexed format.  NULL might work if you don't use such a format, never tried it.

Then there's GDI+, `#include <gdiplus.h>` and the Bitmap class...

Comment: Will this break if the user has multiple displays?

Comment: Could only affect the palette.  Haven't seen a video adapter that could run in 8bpp mode for a *long* time.  Good riddance.

Answer (score 1):

try this. it worked.

```
HDC hdcScreen = ::GetDC( NULL );
HDC hdcMemDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen); 
HBITMAP hbmScreen = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, cx, cy);
HBITMAP hOldBitmap  =  (HBITMAP) ::SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    MyImageDraw(hdcMemDC, ...);

    // The drawing image is held in hBitmap. You can save it
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hdcMemDC,  hOldBitmap); 

    // save The trend image into c:\test.bmp
    PBITMAPINFO pbi = CreateBitmapInfoStruct(hBitmap);
CreateBMPFile("C:\\Temp\\test.bmp", pbi, hBitmap, hdcMemDC);

    //Clean up
::DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
::DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
::ReleaseDC( NULL, hdcScreen );
```